# Get String of first Argument of an function-call

Tags: php, regex

I want to search withing PHP-Files for a special function call. The reason is, that I want to generate .MO-Files for the GetText-Extension. So I first need to create a .PO-Files, which contains all the needed text-strings.

I already find a lot of texts, but there are some problems.

Here is my Regex to find the first Argument of an functioncall:

```
/\_\([\'|\"]{1}(.+?[^\\\])[\'|\"]{1}[,]{0,1}.*?\)+/si
```

I need to find function-calls with the following patterns:

```
_("text");
_("text %s", 3);
_('text');
```

The Text could contain escaped Quotes. My Problem is acuallty, that I need to know, if there was an apostrophe or an normal quote used for the call.

If I have the call

```
_('"text"');
```

then i get the Problem, that I get the text

```
"text
```

without the ending quote.

Does anybody of you have an Idea, how I can get my Regex to work?

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using the xgettext programs to gather the strings?

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: I already have a DB with texts for templates. Theres also a tool to translate the texts. Thats why I want to have all done by this tool, also the PHP-Texts.

It actually works good, I only had a problem with the '"text"' string.. What would you improve, or what isn't valid? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use PHP's [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) for this kind of stuff, not regular expressions:

```
$funcName = '_';
$tokens   = token_get_all(file_get_contents('path/to/your/script.php'));
$strings  = array();

foreach($tokens as $index => $token){

  if(!is_array($token))
    continue;

  if($token[0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING){

    if(!isset($tokens[$index - 2]) || ($tokens[$index - 1] !== "("))
      continue;

    list($id, $text, $line) = $tokens[$index - 2];

    // this is your string (substr drops quotes around it)
    if(($id === T_STRING) && ($text === $funcName))
      $strings[] = substr($token[1], 1, -1);

  }    
}

var_dump($strings);
```

Comment: +1 For cleaner solution, but I wonder why not start with the function name instead of the string.

Comment: No reason, just my choice.

Answer (score 2):

Raw regex:

```
_\((?|'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'|"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)")
```

Delimited regex:

```
~_\((?|'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'|"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)")~
```

The result is in capturing group 1. I used the branch reset pattern `(?|pattern)` so that the capturing group number is reset for each alternating branch separated by `|`.

Inside of the branch reset `(?|'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'|"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)")` are 2 pattern:

- `'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'`: Match and capture content inside single quoted string, which consists of either non-quote-non-backslash or escaped sequence. Actually, I am a bit careless here, since (raw) new line character is considered part of the string. I don't think the specification would allow this, but if the input contains valid code, then there should be no problem.
- `"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"`: Same as above, but for double quoted string.

Note that I don't consume the rest of the arguments to the function.

Comment: works actually good, but when i have the string "hallo <span color=\"#00000\">text</color>" it is splitted after the \

Comment: It now seems to work perfectly. But I got the error "Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 51 in ..", so I added tow more backslashes. It know looks like that: preg_match_all('~_\((?|\'((?:[^\'\\\]|\\.)*)\'|"((?:[^"\\\]|\\.)*)")~', ...);

Comment: @KevinGlier: Ah, since you need to put the regex into a string, you will need to escape accordingly. But have you tried the other solution? It is **much more** reliable than regex.

Comment: Yes, I tried it now and it really looks cleaner and I will better use it, because it must be more reliable. But thanks for your Regex ;)

Comment: @KevinGlier: It's nice that PHP has a lexer built-in and it is so easy to use. Nice learning something new :)